# Is there a way to convert Unreal ASSET/RESS files back into their original code?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I know that for Unity, there are are asset debundlers and package managers, but if you are wanting to convert an Unreal ASSET/RESS file back into its original code, is there a way to do this? I have tried to find information on this, but it seems there either isn't a way to do this, or I am looking in the wrong places.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean? .uassets don’t come from any code to convert back to…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience I've never been able to get directly from .uasset. BUT, in my opinion you have two options:

- 1 export asset to get the main file. (Works best for meshes and textures)
  [image]
- 2 find the source file from hovering texture. (If you only work with your pc works best)
  [image]